# Too many echos used in php else if?

Tags: php

This is the code I currently have that I want to update

```
<?php
if ($admin != null) {
    if ($admin->get_permissions()==3) echo "Welcome Administrator"; 
    elseif ($admin->get_permissions()==1) echo 'Welcome User';
}
else echo 'Welcome guest.';
```

Now what I want to display is more along the lines of

```
<?php
if ($admin != null) {
    if ($admin->get_permissions()==3) echo '<center><br>Welcome';  
    echo $admin->get_nicename();
    echo '<br /><center>
        <p></p>
        <p>&nbsp; </p>
        <p>Basic Information about your account~ </p>
        <p>
        Username:';  
    echo $_SESSION['admin_login']; 
    echo'</p>
        <p>
        Email:'; 
    echo $admin->get_email(); 
    echo '</p>
        <p>
        Admin Level:';
    echo $admin->get_permissions(); 
    echo '<p>
        <p><hr />
        </center>

        <p>';
```

Now when I try to get that to run through it gives me a bad syntax on my next else if; my other issue is I do have a javascript button that I'm not sure how to have implemented into the php else if line; the button itself is

`<input type="button" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='logout.php'" value="Logout" />`
I know the code is sloppy, but I'm not really sure how I can get this variable set up any other way.

Comment: You missed the closing brace `}`.

Comment: give braces for the second `if` condition

Comment: curly braces are your friend - I use them exclusively and have trained myself to stop using oneliner if/elseif/else statements

Comment: The braces were my issue? What do you mean by oneliner if/elseif/else statements? When I set the variable I have to break the previous echo and create a new one unless there's something that I'm missing.

Comment: Use some basic debugging. It looks like you are using SO as step by step to build your site on every case. Your above code was given by user just a while ago. If you want to learn, try yourself 1st. Don't overuse stackoverflow.

Comment: onliner if/elseif/else statements are statements that have no curly braces to contain the code to be executed - the script will execute the next line or up to the next semicolon for the condition

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the opening brace if the if:

```
if ($admin->get_permissions()==3) { echo '<center><br>Welcome'; 
//                                ^^ missing
```

At the end I do not see a closing brace, it is not clear to me if you posted all of the script.

I would suggest making your code more readable. There are different ways to do that.

With a include for example:

```
if ($admin != null) {
  if ($admin->get_permissions()==3) { 
     include 'user_welcome.php';
  }
  // do other stuf here
}
```

or if there is a lot of html use a end php tag:

```
    if ($admin != null) {
      if ($admin->get_permissions()==3) { ?>
        <center>
          <br>
          Welcome <?php echo $admin->get_nicename(); ?><br />
        </center>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p>
          &nbsp; 
        </p>
        <p>
          Basic Information about your account~ </p>
        <p>
          Username: <?php echo $_SESSION['admin_login']; ?> 
        </p>
        <p>
        <!-- the rest of the html code -->
    <?php } // closing the sceond if
} // closing the first if
```

Comment: Wouldn't closing out the php tag end the else if statement?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go buddy: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Read up on your syntax.  Your missing brackets in your code as JvdBerg, KingCrunch and the others have said.  You can use if statements without brackets, but your not doing it properly.

Give that link a quick once over.  Also, in my opinion you have way too many echo statements check into using:

```
<?
$str = <<<EOF
blah, blah, blah, blah some text  and  a $variable 
blah, blah some <html> code, etc. ...
EOF;
?>
```

Now the EOF can be renamed to anything, but make sure it's unique and doesn't have a constant assigned to it.  As you can see, it will make your code look much more legible.

Also, you have an html issue.  Your < center > tag doesn't have a closing.  Keep programming, but brush up on that link I sent, and study your code a little bit more before posting a questions like this.